# can i send lists to firestore for 1 field

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Can i send lists to firestore for 1  field?

get list from firebase

```
List<ItemSell>? _itemsell;

 Future getItemList() async {
    var itemData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('cart')
        .get();
    setState(() {
      _itemsell =
          List.from(itemData.docs.map((doc) => ItemSell.fromSnapshot(doc)));
    });
  }
```

add to firebase

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("users")
                  .doc(uid)
                  .collection("orders")
                  .add({
                "uid": uid,
                "mid": widget._merchant.userid,
                "uname": username,
                "utel": usertel,
                "mname": widget._merchant.name,
                "mtel": widget._merchant.tel,
                "sellitemlist": _itemsell,
              })
```

class that i use for list

```
class ItemSell {
  String type = '';
  String brand = '';
  String model = '';
  String itemid = '';
  String itemcartid = '';
  double itemprice = 0.0;
  ItemSell(this.type, this.brand, this.model, this.itemid, this.itemprice);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'itemtype': type,
        'itembrand': brand,
        'itemmodel': model,
        'uid': itemid,
        'itemprice': itemprice,
        'icid': itemcartid,
      };
  ItemSell.fromSnapshot(snapshot)
      : type = snapshot.data()['itemtype'],
        brand = snapshot.data()['itembrand'],
        model = snapshot.data()['itemmodel'],
        itemprice = snapshot.data()['itemprice'],
        itemcartid = snapshot.data()['icid'],
        itemid = snapshot.data()['uid'];
}
```

[image]

i try to send list to firestore but it's null.do i need to change somthing or any advice?

Comment: None of the fields in your `ItemSell` class is a list. Can you clarify which field you expect to be stored as a list, and also show a database screenshot of how you'd like it to be stored?

Comment: thank you for your answer, i want to make Itemsell to sellitem in firestore.
can i do that?
@FrankvanPuffelen